# How to jump into REPL after the execution of an Hardhat script?

Tags: hardhat

Is it possible with Hardhat to launch a script, wait for its completion (or an error), and then jump into the console, with access to the current environment variables?

When using eth-brownie, or python in general, you can add the -i flag to achieve this. Does the equivalent exist with node/hardhat? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807716/how-to-jump-into-repl-after-the-execution-of-a-node-js-script/71807898#71807898):

"You can use repl.start() at the end of your code to do that.

```js
const repl = require("repl");

const myVariable = 1;
console.log("myVariable: ", myVariable);
// provide extra contexts here to access in the REPL
repl.start().context.myVariable = myVariable;
```

Note that by default only global variables are accessible in the REPL. If you want to access other variables, you must pass them via context"

```
repl.start().context.yourVariable
```